# Python: Creating a hollow 3D model in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to create the same model as the one which is in the picture bellow. [image: 3D model of boundary surface]
The model which I get is not hollow inside.
[image: Matplolib image of the model]
Here is the code which I used for creating that model.

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib import cm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.mlab import griddata
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

data = np.genfromtxt('data.txt')
x = data[:, 0]
y = data[:, 1]
z = data[:, 2]
xi = np.linspace(min(x), max(x))
yi = np.linspace(min(y), max(y))

X, Y = np.meshgrid(xi, yi)
Z = griddata(x, y, z, xi, yi, interp='linear')

surf = ax.plot_trisurf(x, y, z, cmap=cm.jet, linewidth=0.1)


ax.set_zlim3d(np.min(Z), np.max(Z))
fig.colorbar(surf)

plt.show()
```

How should I fix my code in order to get the same model? Here is the [data.txt file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B92Nk-QHod5xVG44ZjZMdElMd2M/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: Your data file just have coordinates. You also need a connectivity for using ``trisurf``.

Comment: Indeed, your data looks like a helicoid. So I think that you need to provide the connectivity, since 15044 does not seem to have a divisor around 40 to reshape your data.

Comment: I don't get it. What do you mean by connectivity?

Comment: A collection of points doesn't create a surface. For a surface you need a collection of "facets", how points are order to create these facets/triangles/polygons is normally referred as connectivity. You can check this [explanation] (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon_mesh). Basically, the points should be located in the corners of the polygons, in this case, triangles. That information is missing from your file.

Comment: Alright, now I get it. So with that data set which I have I won't be able to create the desired model with using 'trisurf'. Is there a different way to solve this problem with using this data set or do I need to fix my data?

Comment: Sometimes, your data is ordered in some sort of grid (rectangular, polar) and the connectivity is obvious. You need to write your data as a m x n array. In your case, it does not seem to be possible. Nevertheless, it seems that your data has some sort of structure, something like helicoidal. I can't just tell you how is it, I don't have enough time to go and check it.